# adapting class based library to react hooksv

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am migrating a class-based component to hooks. The component is using `react-form-validator-core`;

the library exposes validatorForm which can be used like this:

```
<ValidatorForm
            ref="form"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        >
            <FileValidator
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                name="file"
                type="file"
                value={file}
                validators={['isFile', 'maxFileSize:' + 1 * 1024 * 1024, 'allowedExtensions:image/png,image/jpeg']}
                errorMessages={['File is not valid', 'Size must not exceed 1MB', 'Only png and jpeg']}
            />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
</ValidatorForm>
```

it used older ref to get access to form instance to access a few methods. The library has no hook support.
Is there any way to adapt this to react hooks or do I have to replace the form library?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [react-form-validator-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-validator-core) doc here
you can see an example of the ref that they are using.

`ref={(r) => { this.input = r; }}`

This syntax usage of ref in the Class components in React will bind the DOM element to a class property.

In functional components, you can use the `useRef` hook that will allow you to get the same result. [see official react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

So you can try something like this (I didn't test it)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ValidatorComponent, ValidatorForm } from 'react-form-validator-core';

const Component = () => {
const formRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <ValidatorForm
      ref=formRef
      onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
    >
      <FileValidator
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        name="file"
        type="file"
        value={file}
        validators={['isFile', 'maxFileSize:' + 1 * 1024 * 1024, 'allowedExtensions:image/png,image/jpeg']}
        errorMessages={['File is not valid', 'Size must not exceed 1MB', 'Only png and jpeg']}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </ValidatorForm>
  );
}
```

Comment: it doesn't. Tried that.

Comment: @aryansingh I made it work with some changes. I'm updating the code snippet